# TypeError: Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_pushNotifications.pushNotifications.configure') React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification

I am new to React Native and am trying to create push notifications on iOS with push-notification-ios and react-native-push-notification. I am following a number of different tutorials on this as I am still learning how it works.

When I run my app I get the following error.

[image: error]

Here is my code

```js
const configure = async () => {
    console.log('push notification configured');
    PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('registrationError', (e) => {

    PushNotifcation.configure({
        
        onRegister: function(token) {
            //process token
            alert('Token!' + JSON.stringify(token));
            console.log('[CATCHED] onRegister:', token);
            db.setToken(token).catch(
               console.log('[ERROR] device push token has not been saved on the database'), 
            );
        },
        onNotification: async function(notification) {
            console.log('[CATCHED] onNotification:' + JSON.stringify(notification));
            let notifType = '';
            if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                notifType = getNotificationType(
                    JSON.parse(notification.data.data).type,
                );
            } else {
                notifType = getNotificationType(
                    notification.type,
                );
            }
            //process the notification
            //required on iOS only
            if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
            notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
            }
            },
            senderID: '-----',

        permissions: {
            alert: true,
            badge: true,
            sound: true
        },

        popInitialNotification: true,
        requestPermissions: true,
    });
    });
}

export {
    configure,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 5: you typed `PushNotifcation` instead `PushNotification`.

The fixed code is here:

```js
const configure = async () => {
    console.log('push notification configured');
    PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('registrationError', (e) => {

    PushNotification.configure({

        onRegister: function(token) {
            //process token
            alert('Token!' + JSON.stringify(token));
            console.log('[CATCHED] onRegister:', token);
            db.setToken(token).catch(
               console.log('[ERROR] device push token has not been saved on the database'), 
            );
        },
        onNotification: async function(notification) {
            console.log('[CATCHED] onNotification:' + JSON.stringify(notification));
            let notifType = '';
            if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                notifType = getNotificationType(
                    JSON.parse(notification.data.data).type,
                );
            } else {
                notifType = getNotificationType(
                    notification.type,
                );
            }
            //process the notification
            //required on iOS only
            if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
            }
            },
            senderID: '-----',

        permissions: {
            alert: true,
            badge: true,
            sound: true
        },

        popInitialNotification: true,
        requestPermissions: true,
    });
    });
}

export {
    configure,
};
```

Comment: fixed this but sadly still having the same problem

Comment: Your code don't show an dependency import => var PushNotification = require("react-native-push-notification");

Comment: I have import PushNotificationIOS from '@react-native-community/push-notification-ios';
import PushNotification from "react-native-push-notification"; at the top of the file

Comment: I viewed issues related to this. Please, try other import variations (some people fixed doing this): var PushNotification = require("react-native-push-notification");

Comment: Btw, did you link the native module ("react-native-push-notification") to your project?

Comment: I have done both of these already and still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You have re-build your app try:

- `yarn android`

OR

- `cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android`

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Your import must be the wrong path

Try this:

```
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';
import PushNotificationIOS from '@react-native-community/push-notificatio-ios';
```